# Need some help on mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test3");

$hs_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%'; //changed this and it worked!
$nv_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%';
$vsa_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%';

$query = $mysqli->stmt_init();
//create a prepared statement


$query = "SELECT hs,nv,vsa FROM handover WHERE hs like ? or nv like ? or vsa like ?";
//$query = "SELECT id,hs,nv,vsa FROM sectona_product WHERE hs = ? or nv = ?";



$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('sss',$hs_data,$nv_data,$vsa_data);

//execute query
$statement->execute();

//bind result variables to be printed
$statement->bind_result( $hs,$nv,$vsa);

$statement->store_result();
if( $statement->num_rows > 0 )
{

print '<table border="1">'; 
print '<tr>';
//fetch records
while($statement->fetch()) {


print '<td>'.$hs.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$nv.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$vsa.'</td>';
print '</tr>';

}   
print '</table>';

} else {

print "<p>No Rows</p>";
}
//close connection
$statement->close();

?>
```

Final working code with massive help from sectona - just for everyone to clearly see. This for a keyword search on a input called hs_data. Im checking columns in my database hs,nv,vsa it prints matching results into a table.

Comment: What is the value of `$key`? Have you run the query manually? You may need wildcards because of the `LIKE` (`$key = '%'. $_POST['key'] .'%';`)

Comment: The prepared statement simply substitutes the variable's value in, but in a safer way that doing string concatenation. But the SQL operates the same as if you'd done the substitution, so there's nothing really to explain.

Comment: The value of key is the name attribute of the input field that the user enters the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has been tested and it works now

First create table and insert records

```
create table sectona_product(id int primary key auto_increment, hs varchar(100), nv varchar(80),vsa varchar(86));
insert into sectona_product(hs,nv,vsa) values('jon','gab','secunda');

<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root_password", "sectona_db");

$hs_data = 'jon';
$nv_data = 'gab';

$query = $mysqli->stmt_init();
//create a prepared statement


$query = "SELECT id,hs,nv,vsa FROM sectona_product WHERE hs like ? or nv like ?";
//$query = "SELECT id,hs,nv,vsa FROM sectona_product WHERE hs = ? or nv = ?";



$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('ss',$hs_data,$nv_data);

//execute query
$statement->execute();

//bind result variables to be printed
$statement->bind_result($id, $hs, $nv,$vsa);

Print "Your data is printed successfully";
print '<table border="1">';

//fetch records
while($statement->fetch()) {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>'.$id.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$hs.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$nv.'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$vsa.'</td>';

    print '</tr>';
}   
print '</table>';

//close connection
$statement->close();

?>
```

If the query is coming from form inputs Eg.

```
<input type=text name="hs_data" id="hs_data>
```

then you can set the php variable as

```
$hs_data=$_POST['hs_data'];
```

if you still need to protect your script against XSS Attack when outputing or print out data from database, you can 
use either `htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars()`

```
functions as per below

print '<td>'.htmlentities($vsa, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</td>';
```

Please rate and give me a shout if you find it interesting. ....Sectona

Comment: This works in the way that for the first time I am seeing my tables. However it does not search against my string. For example I have a string hello in my table but it gets the the whole column when I input. I have to rate you purely for your time and the mass of stuff you ave shown. I will post my code that bring up table just in case you feel like helping a tiny bit more but you have done more than enough and I can post another question if I cant work it out. Thankyou

Comment: just post everything so that i can assist you from scratch. both table everything.post them all

Comment: @Sectona Please edit the answer to merge it with the other one, rather than posting two answers.

Answer (score 0):

This code should help and I believe it should work for you(Though i have not tested it yet.
I just code it right the way)
First you need to be able to differentiate between intger and varchar family data.
In Mysqli, Interger, Numbers are represented by i and varchar family by s
hence  in your binding, you may have somthing like

```
$stmt->bind_param('sis',$varchar,$integer,$text); etc.
```

Follow this code and your problem is solved. Give me a shout if you still cannot resolve it.
Thanks .. Sectona

```
<?
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root777", "sectona_db");

$hs_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%'; //changed this and it worked!
$nv_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%';
$vsa_data= '%' .$_POST['hs_data']. '%';
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM handover WHERE hs LIKE ? OR nv LIKE ? OR vsa LIKE ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$hs1,$nv1,$vsa1);
 $stmt->execute();

    // Close statement object
    $stmt->close();
print "<font size=4 color=green>Query Successful </font>";
}
else{
print "<font size=4 color=red>Somethin is wrong somewhere </font>";
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for anwsering. I getsome errors from that script. Il add .

Comment: Please am in the office assisting my father. In less than 5 hours I will get it working for you because by that time i will be at home. Thanks

Comment: Secondly, I will also advice you to move from mysqli to PDO. PDO is the best ans easiest.

Comment: Hello I changed the posts and added the %s il add and it works